# Same AJAX request in different machines returns in different format

Tags: javascript, ajax

I´m having the following issue: if I make an AJAX request on my dev environment, I get the following (abbreviated) raw result:

```
{
  "id": 37988,
  "technique_id": 20,
  "task_area_id": 1,
  "task_area_name": "Gestao",
  "order": 3,
  "text": 437,
  "unscheduled": 0,
  "start_date": "17-10-2018",
  "hours": 4,
  "adjusted_hours": 4,
  "done_hours": 0,
  "duration": 1,
  "progress": null,
  "status": null,
  "worker": 53,
  "priority": 1,
  "parent": 236,
  "readonly": 0,
  "cancreate": 0
},
```

On the other hand, when I call it on my prod environment:

```
{
  "id": "37988",
  "technique_id": "20",
  "task_area_id": "1",
  "task_area_name": "Gest\u00e3o",
  "order": "3",
  "text": "437",
  "unscheduled": "0",
  "start_date": "17-10-2018",
  "hours": "4",
  "adjusted_hours": "4",
  "done_hours": "0",
  "duration": "1",
  "progress": null,
  "status": null,
  "worker": "53",
  "priority": "1",
  "parent": "236",
  "readonly": "0",
  "cancreate": "0"
},
```

Notice that on my prod int values get converted to strings.
The code is the same, the database is the same.

The database call is also the same, and in both cases numbers are returned as int, so why in one case the int format is preserved and on the other it's converted to string?

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide some more info ? like if you hitting the same service from local and dev , it should return the same data and structure. can you check any any config is there

Comment: Same or different browsers? Same or different OS? Same or different environment in any way (e.g., language settings, or some user settings on the website itself)? Probably also important is how is the *backend* generating different results? It might be that in dev the response generation has been changed. Or there is some conditional thing going on.

Comment: no offense, but it seems to be difference in server script

Comment: Is your back-end in PHP MySQl?

Comment: Problem might be in your backend code that gives "task_area_name". Can you add that one in detail?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from task_area_name \u00e - it has the different format (encoding).

The problem can be in request headers or in webserver config.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: In prod environment he is getting output as javascript object.So stringify is needed.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` would change nothing here. If the values are strings, they would remain strings. If they are numbers, they'd remain numbers. `{ "id": 37988 }` will not change to `{ "id": "37988" }` or vice versa through either using `JSON.stringify` on an object or `JSON.parse` on a string representation of this data.